# CCAvenue non seamless URL not getting loaded in UIWebView

Tags: ios, swift3, uiwebview, ccavenue

I am using non-seamless transaction type in my iOS app. I am loading https://secure.ccavenue.com/transaction/initTrans URL in UIWebView after getting the RSA key. Sometimes it is getting loaded and sometimes it is blank white UIWebView, in this case, though the delegate method for UIWebView,

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView)
```

is getting called. It is not throwing any error or something.

Below is the code for the same.

```
func ApiCallForRSAKey(){

    let stringRsaKeyData = "access_code=\(stringAccessCodePayment)&order_id=\(stringGloabalCart_ID)"
    stringResultAddress = "\(dictionaryGloabalAddress["address_title"]!)"+","+"\(dictionaryGloabalAddress["address_1"]!)"+","+"\(dictionaryGloabalAddress["address_2"]!)" as NSString
    let requestData = NSData(bytes: stringRsaKeyData.cString(using: .utf8), length: stringRsaKeyData.characters.count) as NSData
    let rsaRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: urlGetRSAURL) as! URL) as NSMutableURLRequest
    rsaRequest.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "content-type")
    rsaRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
    rsaRequest.addValue("\(accessKey!)", forHTTPHeaderField: "access_key")
    rsaRequest.addValue("\(userDictionary.value(forKey: "user_key")!)", forHTTPHeaderField: "user_key")
    rsaRequest.httpBody = requestData as Data

    let session = URLSession.shared

    let task = session.dataTask(with: rsaRequest as URLRequest, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in

        do{
            let dictionaryResultRSAKey = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data! as Data, options: .mutableContainers) as! NSDictionary

            if dictionaryResultRSAKey.value(forKey: "response_code")! is NSNull {
                self.viewForIndicator.isHidden = true
                self.viewRetryView.isHidden = false
            }else{
                if(dictionaryResultRSAKey.value(forKey: "response_code")! as! NSInteger == 1111){

                    self.viewRetryView.isHidden = true
                    let dictionary = dictionaryResultRSAKey["data"] as! NSDictionary
                    var stringRSAKey = "\(dictionary["rsaKey"]!)" as NSString

                    if(stringRSAKey == ""){
                        Toast(text: NSLocalizedString("stringSomethingWentWrong", comment: ""), duration: 2).show()

                    }else{
                        stringRSAKey = stringRSAKey.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines) as NSString
                        stringRSAKey = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n\(stringRSAKey)\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----" as NSString
                        let stringRequestParam = "amount=\(1)&currency=\(stringCurrencyValue)"
                        //                    let stringRequestParam = "amount=\(stringAmount_Pay)&currency=\(stringCurrencyValue)"
                        let ccTool = CCTool()
                        var stringEncryptValue :NSString = ccTool.encryptRSA(stringRequestParam, key: (stringRSAKey as NSString) as String!) as NSString
                        let regExpStr : String = "!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]"
                        stringEncryptValue = CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(nil, stringEncryptValue as CFString, nil, (regExpStr as CFString), CFStringBuiltInEncodings.UTF8.rawValue) as String as String as NSString
                        let stringEncryptedValue = "access_code="+"\(stringAccessCodePayment)"+"&merchant_id="+"\(stringMerchantID)"+"&order_id="+"\(stringGloabalCart_ID)"+"&redirect_url="+"\(urlRedirectURL)"+"&cancel_url="+"\(urlCancelTransactionURL)"+"&enc_val="+"\(stringEncryptValue)"+"&billing_name="+"\(stringPersonName_Order)"+"&billing_address="+"\(self.stringResultAddress)"+"&billing_tel="+"\(stringContactNo_shipping)"+"&billing_city="+"\(dictionaryGloabalAddress["city"]!)"+"&billing_state="+"\(dictionaryGloabalAddress["state"]!)"+"&billing_zip="+"\(dictionaryGloabalAddress["zipcode"]!)"+"&billing_country="+"\(dictionaryGloabalAddress["country"]!)"+"&billing_email="+"\(userDictionary["email"]!)"
                        print(stringEncryptedValue)
                        let myRequestData = NSData.init(bytes: stringEncryptedValue.cString(using: .utf8), length: stringEncryptedValue.characters.count) as NSData
                        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: urlTrasnsactionURL) as! URL) as NSMutableURLRequest
                        request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "content-type")
                        request.setValue(urlTrasnsactionURL, forHTTPHeaderField: "Referer")
                        request.httpMethod = "POST"
                        request.httpBody = myRequestData as Data

                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(2), execute: {
                            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                                self.webviewForPayment.loadRequest((request as NSMutableURLRequest) as URLRequest)
                            })
                        })

                    }
                }else{

                }
            }

        }catch{

        }
    })

    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: Where are you testing this ( Simulator / actual device ). When you hit blank page, try to open same url outside app in safari to see if you get any response?

Comment: you might want to try setting NSAllowsArbitraryLoads value for http connection

Comment: can u explain what u r doing after payment button click. step by step .. then for me easy to resolve ur issue

Comment: as per ur question u r saying 1.sometimes u r getting the payment page and some times not getting.-- for this one reason  after u getting the rsa key u need to hit.  https://secure.ccavenue.com/transaction/initTrans  for payment page with in 120 sec